# Translating Prototype Ajax call into jQuery (adding form parameters and loading function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, prototypejs

I am trying to translate this on submit call into a identical call in jquery

```
onsubmit = "new Ajax.Updater('graph','/test/add', {asynchronous: true, evalScripts: true,
    onLoading:function(request){document.getElementById('load').style.display='block'}, parameters:Form.serialize(this)});
```

So far I have this function:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
 $.ajax({
    url: '/saffron_main/click_out_display',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#graph').html(data);
    }
});

});
```

However, I am having trouble replicating two pieces of functionality.

1. `parameters:Form.serialize(this)`
2. `onLoading:function(request){document.getElementById('load').style.display='block'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function(e){

 $.ajax({
    url: '/saffron_main/click_out_display',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#graph').html(data);
        $("#load").css("display","block");
    }
});

});
```

That should match your needs. If anything is unclear, don't hesistate to ask.